# Undefined references in Apache user-written module

Tags: apache

I have some undefined reference errors in an Apache module.  I've cut the source code down to a minimum that reproduced the error.  Below is the source for "mod_test.c" ...

```
#include "httpd.h"
#include "http_config.h"
#include "http_request.h"
#include "http_protocol.h"
#include "http_core.h"
#include "http_main.h"
#include "http_log.h"
#include "ap_mpm.h"
#include "apr_strings.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

module AP_MODULE_DECLARE_DATA test_module;

static int test_handler(request_rec *r);
static int test_init(apr_pool_t *p, apr_pool_t *plog, apr_pool_t *ptemp, server_rec *s);

/* Structure containing state information for the module */

typedef struct {
} ns_mod_config;


static int ns_typematch(request_rec *r) {

  ns_mod_config *ns_scfg = ap_get_module_config(r->server->module_config,
                                          &test_module);

  core_request_config *creq_cfg;
  creq_cfg = ap_get_core_module_config(r->request_config);

  return 0;
}


module AP_MODULE_DECLARE_DATA test_module = {
        STANDARD20_MODULE_STUFF,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL};
```

I am using a more-or-less standard Makefile for compiling the module (note that the install option has been removed as this is a test to demonstrate the problem.)

```
APXS=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs
APXS_OPTS=-Wc, -Wc,-DDST_CLASS=3
SRC=src/mod_test.c
OBJ=src/.libs/mod_test.so

$(OBJ): $(SRC)
        @echo
        $(APXS) $(APXS_OPTS) -c $(SRC)
        @echo
        @echo write '"make install"' to install module
        @echo

clean:
        rm -f src/.libs/*
        rm -f src/*.o
        rm -f src/*.lo
        rm -f src/*.la
        rm -f src/*.slo
        rmdir src/.libs
```

The compile fails as follows:

```
/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs -Wc, -Wc,-DDST_CLASS=3 -c src/mod_test.c
/usr/local/apache2/build/libtool --silent --mode=compile gcc -prefer-pic   -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -g -O2 -pthread -I/usr/local/apache2/include  -I/usr/local/apache2/include   -I/usr/local/apache2/include   -DDST_CLASS=3  -c -o src/mod_test.lo src/mod_test.c && touch src/mod_test.slo
src/mod_test.c: In function âns_typematchâ:
src/mod_test.c:34:3: error: unknown type name âcore_request_configâ
   core_request_config *creq_cfg;
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/mod_test.c:35:14: warning: implicit declaration of function âap_get_core_module_configâ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   creq_cfg = ap_get_core_module_config(r->request_config);
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/mod_test.c:35:12: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   creq_cfg = ap_get_core_module_config(r->request_config);
            ^
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
.
Makefile:23: recipe for target 'src/.libs/mod_test.so' failed
make: *** [src/.libs/mod_test.so] Error 1
```

I am not sure how this can occur.  http_core.h is present in /usr/local/apache2/include and it does include the definitions that are claimed missing by the compile.  Six other modules on the same system compile without errors, though none of them use this specific reference to the core data structures.

Help will be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

After posting to the Apache modules mailing list, it develops that the problem is in two parts.

1. Defining CORE_PRIVATE is required under Apache 2.2 to have access to the core data structures.
2. ap_get_core_module_config is an Apache 2.4 construct.